# How to read the JSON file using jQuery in ASP.NET?

Tags: json, jquery

I have tried this alot but always I am getting the failure problem .Can any one guide how can we read the json file using jQuery?I have a json file in my project as given in this image
[image: JSON FILE]

i have written the code as given below

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnLoad').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "example.json",
                    dataType: "text/json",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            });
        });

        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            alert(result.d);
        }
        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }
```

But It is always AjaxFailed is firing.

Comment: Try `dataType: "json"`. Also, what does the alert in `AjaxFailed()` actually say?

Comment: I had a problem like this before. Mine was because of IIS Mime types. Check Mime Types on IIS. Should entry for json. Extension: '.json' MIME Type: 'application/json'

Comment: @nnnnnn That "AjaxFailed" is a Method.

Comment: I know it's a method. I was asking what message is actually displayed by the `alert()` when `AjaxFailed()` is invoked.

Comment: @nnnnnn  It is showing the Message as "404 Not Found"

Comment: I have follwed this link only http://netprogramminghelp.com/ajax/how-to-getfindretrieve-datavalues-from-json-file-using-jquery-aspnet/

Answer (score 2):

`dataType` should be `'JSON'`

There are only 4 accepted values for `dataType`, which you can see here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Also, your `error` function takes 3 parameters:

```
errorFn(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // your code
}
```

Additionally, this:

```
success: function (msg) {
    AjaxSucceeded(msg);
},
```

Can be this:

```
success: AjaxSucceeded
```

Your success function also takes 3 parameters:

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

For reference on `$.ajax` parameters: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The success function can take three parameters, but you don't have to define them all if you're not using them.

Comment: Right, but it is good to know what these three parameters are should you need to use them.